# Cordova visual studio builds does not effects

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

i'm building my first app with Visual Studio 2013 and Cordova. I can see my app on Ripple correctly, but when I try to build and create the .apk, it says that the building is finished, but I cannot find the package in Release directory.
I can't understand why...
Here the output log:

```
1>------ Inizio compilazione: Progetto: AppProva, Configurazione: Release Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : Al compilatore TypeScript Compiler non è stato fornito alcun file per la compilazione. La compilazione verrà ignorata.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  C:\Prj\App\AppProva\AppProva>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\rpawfip1.hs4\packages\vs-mda
========== Compilazione: 1 completate, 0 non riuscite, 0 aggiornate, 0 ignorate ==========
```

Tnx

Comment: Did you set build to the "Release" option? Maybe it's in the "Debug" mode and folder?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think VS will do the Android build unless you have it specified as the build target.  Meaning, each time it launches Ripple, it doesn't take the time to build any of the other platforms. Try changing your build target to Android anything and do a build.